# Notepad++ script permission denied to text file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some information and then add it to a text file but when I run the script, I get the following error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'stocks.txt'

I'm doing this for adding to the file.

```
f = open("stocks.txt", "a")
f.write(containers[0].string + "\n")
f.close()
```

When I go to my file explorer and right click the program and press run, it prints to the file but any other way gives me the error.

Comment: Either the file used by some other program and won't allow you to open the file for writing or the code you try to run does not have writing permissions to that file

Comment: i think you are running in windows. if yes, you can run first notepad++ `run as administrator`. and see if you can create file.

Comment: 'textfile'???? where is it in your code?

Comment: That was my mistake, it now correctly says the name of the text file. @Karthikeyan KR

Comment: The file is in my PycharmProjects folder and the text file is in there on the same level. It writes when I run it through file explorer but not through Pycharm for some reason. Is it something having to do with changing the program's configuration? @AndreyF